# How to pass runtime ENV variables to a Docker container that's used to run a GitlabCI job?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

**Context:**

We use self-hosted Docker containers to run our GitlabCI jobs in order to build/test mobile projects. For this we have a custom Docker image that we build based on a custom `Dockerfile`, then publish on Artifact Registry and subsequently use for containers in all our standalone mobile projects.

Each mobile project that we want to run on GitlabCI has its own `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in which we specify all the project specific build stages and also the image that should be used for all build stages mentioned previously like such (and like the [official documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-in-the-gitlab-ciyml-file)), at the beginning of the file (not production code, just for demo purposes):

```
image: eu.gcr.io/android-build-image:1.0.0
```

**Question:**

We'd like to pass a runtime variable from each project's `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to the Docker container during the container initialisation time, so that we can configure some host ENVs inside the `Dockerfile`, before running any sort of project specific build steps. How can that be achieved?

Comment: What is "image initialisation time"? Why not use `variables:`? How about just running a script in the docker containers that does what you want to do? How are the ENV variables "runtime"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant container initialisation time. As far as I've understood, `variables:` aren't accessible during container init as part of the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: hi, sorry, what is "container initialization time"? Dockerfile _builds_ an image. Then you use an image that is already build, there is no dockerfile usage in your gitlab. Gitlab downloads build image, it is there, the build of the image has been done long time ago. `image: eu.gcr.io/android-build-image:1.0.0` downloads `eu.gcr.io/android-build-image:1.0.0` and runs it. You can build your own image. Or you can run your own script in the containers before your commands to set some variables.

Comment: By container initialisation time I mean when Docker fires up a new container with the already built image to run a new Gitllab Job.

Comment: When gitlab fires up a new container, it executes docker image entrypoint with a script that contains commands from `before_script:` then `script:` then `after_script:`.  It is documented https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#override-the-entrypoint-of-an-image . There is no other "time", if entrypoint is just `sh`, then your script: runs. If you want to do something, you can do it in `script:` or you can build and publish your own image with a custom entrypoint. You can build your own image or execute your own script, as noted above.

Comment: Yep, got that. However, what we're trying to achieve is basically having a predefined script somehow bundled up as part of the image itself, instead of having to pass that script from within each project `.gitlab-ci.yml` file, essentially having it duplicated across all our projects, which we'd like to avoid.

Essentially, we want to set an ENV variable inside the container dynamically, based on the currently running job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So create a dockerfile:

```
FROM eu.gcr.io/android-build-image:1.0.0
COPY ./yourentrypoint.sh /yourentrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "/yourentrypoint.sh"]
```

`yourentrypoint.sh` may look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if something; then
    export ENV=something
fi
exec "$@"
```

See https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/intro/ and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Variable_Types .

Build and publish that docker image - see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html , https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html , and https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/container_registry/ , also see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html .

Then in `image:` use your image. You may consider `docker inspect eu.gcr.io/android-build-image:1.0.0` to execute the original image entrypoint from your entrypoint.